# Not getting instance of jdbcTemplate using spring annotations

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I'm using Spring jdbcTemplate for making database call but i'm not getting jdbcTemplate instance although i've autowired it.

```
package com.mypackage.dao
@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

public Customer findCustomer(){
      ........... 
    jdbcTemplate.execute ......
      ...........
  }
}
```

In Spring applicationContext.xml

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="3" />
</bean>

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage">
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
        type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>
```

database.properties file

```
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:OQA1
database.username=my_app
database.password=my_app_password
database.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

In which area i'm making mistake ?

----------------Edit : Adding the upper layer ----------------

```
 package com.mypackage.rest

  @Service("customerResource")
  @Path("/customer")
  public class CustomerResource extends AbstractResource{

  @Autowired
  private CustomerDao customerDao;

   }
```

Comment: This looks ok, what exception are you getting ? Is your database.properties file loaded by Spring ? Did you enable tx:annotation-driven ?

Comment: Are you seeing any application exceptions?

Comment: @FredClose Close I don't see any exception except NullPointer due to jpaTemplate instance is not being initialized. I havn't enabled tx:annotation-driven, will that cause this issue ?

Comment: Is `CustomerDaoImpl` in package `com.mypackage`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes. It is.

Comment: Please show the class where you are injecting the `CustomerDaoImpl` and is that class in the `com.mypackage`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've added the upper layer in which i'm injecting the CustomerDao and update the package as well

Comment: And the only error is a NPE when you try to access it?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to access all other API in which i'm not having db call (i.e jpaTemplate)

Comment: I honestly don't see it. Try this: make a `JdbcTemplate` bean declaration and autowire that instead of the `DataSource`.

Comment: How does your service access the customerDao ? Which version of Spring ?

Answer (score 0):

Driver class is wrong it should be

```
database.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: That would make the app unable to startup. The issue is the field isn't autowired.

Comment: Yes I agree, since he is getting null pointer exception for jdbcTemplate but only the difference I could notice was the driver class

Comment: Note that there is a `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` class in the `odjbc14.jar`. I don't know for other jars or if that is the correct driver for thin oracle.

Comment: I'm using ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar which has oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. I changed the configuration but still getting the same issue. I guess, it must be because of spring annotations.

Comment: oh, I was using ojdbc6-11.2.0

Comment: How are accessing CustomerDaoImpl?